# Desenvolver aplicativos para iOS utilizando Java

Tags: java, ios, ide

Estou desenvolvendo meu TCC e ele se baseia no conceito multiplataforma do Java. Porém agora esbarrei em um problema o **XCode IDE** da Apple não compreende os pacotes Java.

Existe alguma ferramenta ou extensão que me permita desenvolver minha aplicação para iOS em Java?

Comment: até onde sei no XCode se usa Objective C apenas

Comment: O contrário disso (**Objective-C** para **Java/Android**) pode ser feito através dessa ferramenta [apportable](http://www.apportable.com/), que por enquanto trabalha bem com games.

Comment: Desenvolva seu aplicativo codificando-o em Java para android no Eclipse e... ...utilize o plugin para eclipse http://gluonhq.com/the-new-gluon-plugin-for-eclipse/ para gerar seu aplicativo para o S.O. iOS utilizado nos iPhones a partir do mesmo código Java!

Answer (score 3):

Se você quer desenvolver para **OSX**, que é o sistema do Mac, pode usar IDEs como Eclipse, Netbeans ou IntelliJ Idea.

Já o **iOS** é o sistema do iPhone/iPad e seus aplicativos são desenvolvidos nativamente na linguagem Objective-C, que é uma extensão do C.

Não creio que o iOS suporte programação em Java (pode até existir algum framework para isso, já que para Android é possível "programar" em Delphi ou C# usando frameworks de terceiros (com Delphi XE6 e Xamarin, respectivamente). Falo "programar" entre aspas porque nem todas as funcionalidades podem ser suportadas - para explorar todas as potencialidades de uma plataforma, você tem que programar usando a linguagem e bibliotecas que oferecem essas funcionalidades nativamente).

Mas mesmo que exista uma forma de programar usando Java, não será um exemplo do conceito de multiplataforma do Java como você quer, porque Delphi por exemplo não é multiplataforma e nem roda em dispositivos móveis, mas ainda assim é possível "programar" para Android (e para iOS) usando Delphi (o aplicativo gerado não é compilado em Delphi e sim na linguagem nativa da plataforma móvel; o Delphi foi usado apenas para gerar uma representação intermediária do código).

Se você quer representar o conceito de multiplataforma para dispositivos móveis, isso será melhor representado pelo uso de HTML/CSS/Javascript e alguma biblioteca do tipo PhoneGap, Titanium, etc., que irão fazer seu código rodar praticamente sem modificações (mas com algumas limitações) em vários sistemas móveis, como Android, iOS, Windows Phone, BlackBerry, Firefox OS, etc.

O comportamento multiplataforma do Java não é bem representado nos dispositivos móveis exceto pelo Android, esse comportamento tem sido voltado mais para permitir o *"write once, run anywhere"* em sistemas desktop e servidores.

Answer (score 2):

Aos olhos da **Apple**, você só consegue utilizar mesmo o **Xcode** em seu **Mac**, desenvolvendo com *Objective-C* ou *Swift*. Digo isso porque outra forma que não seja esta, de certa forma vai contra os princípios da empresa.

Você consegue encontrar outras formas, utilizando *HTML 5*, *JavaScript* e *CSS* com **[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)** e gerar um aplicativo híbrido para **iOS**, ou utilizando *C#* com o **[Xamarin](https://xamarin.com/)** e até mesmo para o seu caso, o **[RoboVM](http://www.robovm.org/)** com *Java*.

Mas como eu disse, são opções que **não** são reconhecidas pela Apple, e dependendo do seu objetivo ou para fins de publicação na própria *App Store*, seu aplicativo pode ser rejeitado. Mas cada caso é um caso, não posso afirmar com 100% de certeza.

Comment: Empresa com princípios complicados, né?

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível desenvolver aplicativos para `iOS` utilizando Java, a linguagem de programação oficial para desenvolver para iOS é `Objective-C`. Criada pela **Apple**.

Se você quer usar Java aconselho desenvolver para **Android**.

Answer (score 0):

Neste **[Link](http://www.dicas-l.com.br/arquivo/programe_em_java_para_ios.php#.U1gTbvldVag)** existe referencia a um plugin chamdo **CodeName One** **gratuito** e **open-source** para eclipse ou NetBeans que permite desenvolver em `java` para `iOS`

No **[site](http://www.codenameone.com/)** deles existem varios cases de aplicativos para diversas plataformas além do iOS, mas, não esquecendo do que foi dito pelo @Piovezan é um fato. Nem todas as funcionalidades da linguagem padrão podem estar disponível e o resultado pode não ser tão performático quanto o o código nativo.

Comment: Um comentário feito no link citado também fala do [PlayN](http://code.google.com/p/playn/), que parece interessante. Mas infelizmente nenhuma dessa soluções representa "o conceito multiplataforma do Java", como quer o OP.

Comment: @Piovezan aparentemente o CodenameOne promete aproveitar o código em todas as plataformas q ele suporta, mas como vão ser vários tipos de dispositivos, será necessário ajustes, o q já é necessário para se fazer uma app para um desktop, web e android.

Comment: Sim. Mas mesmo que não fossem necessários ajustes, o que quis dizer é que os diversos dispositivos móveis disponíveis comercialmente não rodam aplicativos em uma JVM (à exceção das antigas apps J2ME e da DVM, que é a JVM modificada do Android) e que portanto não reproduzem o comportamento multiplataforma do Java como no caso por exemplo das principais plataformas desktop. Comentei isso tendo em mente a proposta de TCC do OP.

Comment: Realmente @Piovezan. Concordo com você, não tinha pensado por este lado. Obrigado pelo ponto de vista.